# How to add iterative text at the end of every line of a file using shell script/C/Python?

Tags: python, c, bash, shell, unix

Currently I have:

a.html
b.html
c.html
d.html
e.html

I want this:

a.html 1.css
b.html 2.css
c.html 3.css
d.html 4.css
e.html 5.css

I know how to add a text at the end of each line like

```
awk '{print $0"append_to_end"}' file
```

But I need to add an iterative text (1.css, 2.css, etc) at the end of every line. How to do this using C or Shell Script or Python? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk` just fine. Basically exactly like that.

```
awk '{print $0 ++i".css"}' file
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have the "file". How do I append the result of this to every line in the file?